# Hardhat stuck testing in mainnet by default

Tags: solidity, hardhat, test

I'm new to hardhat and tried to run some tests. Everything works fine until I try to execute payable functions. Addresses generated with `ethers.getSigners();` have no eth on them. Which made me realise that when running `npx hardhat test` it's actually set on mainnet for some reason. Logging network gives me:

`network is:  { name: 'homestead', chainId: 1, ensAddress: '0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e', _defaultProvider: [Function: func] { renetwork: [Function (anonymous)] } }`

How do I go on about switching back to testing locally with hardhat network?
I've added this to my hardhat.config.js

`networks: { hardhat: { chainId: 31337 } }`
But it stills run tests on chainId 1. Even when trying `npx hardhat test --network localhost`

Any ideas how I could fix that pls ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for the answer, actually for some reason even tho it IS indeed the hardhat local that is running the test in the background, .getDefaultProvider().getNetwork() shows "homestead" chainId 1, and getBalance of an address will show 0 eth...

So in order to access provider when testing locally without a network specified, you should use `ethers.provider.getBalance(xxx)` and not `ethers.getDefaultProvider().getBalance(xxx)`

Comment: You just saved me so much time, this is 100% the issue if you are testing locally.